# Formula concerning partitions of $n$ and their transpose

Tags: number-theory, integer-partitions

I am trying to prove
$$\frac{1}{{n \choose 2}} \sum_j {\lambda_j \choose 2} - {\lambda_j'\choose 2}=\frac{1}{n(n-1)}\sum_j \lambda_j^2 - (2j-1)\lambda_j.$$
Here $\lambda$ is a partition of $n$, i.e. $\lambda_j \geq \lambda_{j+1}\geq 0$ and $\sum_j \lambda_j = n$ and $\lambda'$ is the conjugate partition of $\lambda$, also called the transpose of $\lambda$. This is best explained in the Ferrers diagram, which I cannot typeset at the moment, but you simply reflect along the diagonal to obtain the transpose. (Note we pad the partitions with zeros to get them to be the same length). For reference this is formula (D-2) on p. 40 of [Diaconis](https://jdc.math.uwo.ca/M9140a-2012-summer/Diaconis.pdf).

This *is* for homework, so please only hints and allow me to write out my ideas/attempt.

**Attempt**
I first looked for a necessary condition. We note the following simplifications of the LHS:
$$\frac{1}{{n \choose 2}} \sum_j {\lambda_j \choose 2} - {\lambda_j'\choose 2}=\frac{1}{n(n-1)}\sum_j \lambda_j^2 - \lambda_j -(\lambda_j')^2+\lambda_j'$$
$$=\frac{1}{n(n-1)} \sum_j \lambda_j^2 - (\lambda_j')^2,$$
since $\sum_j \lambda_j = \sum_j \lambda_j' = n$ being partitions of $n$. Thus, for the equation to hold we need $(\lambda_j')^2=(2j-1)\lambda_j$ for all $j$ or $\sum_j (\lambda_j')^2 = \sum_j (2j-1)\lambda_j$. Neither condition I can make out to be sufficient, so I am somewhat at a loss as to how to proceed.

Comment: Looking at the partition $(3,1)$, it's certainly not true that $(\lambda'_j)^2 = (2j-1)\lambda_j$ for all $j$: The conjugate of $(3,1)$ is $(2,1,1)$ and $(\lambda'_1)^2 = 4$ while $(2\cdot1 - 1)\lambda_1 = 3$.  But together, of course, $4+1+1 = 3+3$ as stated.

Comment: @BrianHopkins nice, I suspected the first condition would not be useful since it would not necessarily make $\lambda_j^i$ and integer. But I have been stumped on how to prove the second condition is true in general.

Comment: Typo: i meant $\lambda_j’$ in the above comment

Comment: At the risk of using $\prime$ in multiple ways, here's a very vague suggestion: Since $\binom{\lambda_j}{2}$ involves both $\lambda_j$ and $\lambda_j - 1$, I wonder if the derivative of the partition generating function might be useful somehow, since $(q^n)' = nq^{n-1}$.

Comment: @BrianHopkins I’ll check the pdf for definitions but when I google I see a few different generating functions associated with partitions. In this case would I be looking at $g(x)=\sum_j x^{\lambda_j}$? For then $g’’(1)=2 \sum_j {\lambda_j \choose 2}$ but it is still not apparent to me how to proceed with this yet. I appreciate the suggestion though, I can try a few more ideas now with it.